# How to use order with uniq in a PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How can I use `order` with `uniq`?

```
auction.invoices.get_auction_invoices.item_invoices.
joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = invoices.usable_id").order("users.first_name").uniq
```

The above query gives me following error:

This is my scopes

scope :item_invoices, ->{ joins(:invoice_details).where("invoice_details.invoiceable_type = ?", "Item")}

scope :get_auction_invoices, ->{where(:id => (item_invoices.skip_cancelled_invoice + donators.skip_cancelled_invoice))}

> PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
>   LINE 1: ...oice_details.invoiceable_type = 'Item')  ORDER BY users.firs...
>   : SELECT DISTINCT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" INNER JOIN "invoice_details" ON "invoice_details"."invoice_id" = "invoices"."id" INNER JOIN users ON users.id = invoices.usable_id WHERE "invoices"."eventable_id" = $1 AND "invoices"."eventable_type" = $2 AND "invoices"."id" IN (1132, 1131, 777, 777, 777, 3013, 3024, 3024, 3024, 3024, 3041, 3041, 3013) AND (invoice_details.invoiceable_type = 'Item')  ORDER BY users.first_name

Comment: how did you describe `auction.invoices.get_auction_invoices.item_invoices` in models?

Comment: also please provide generated SQL for the line (do with `#to_sql`)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, this is my scopes which i'm define in my Invoice Model

Comment: could you show part of your models involved in?

Comment: scope :get_auction_invoices, ->{where(:id => (item_invoices.skip_cancelled_invoice + donators.skip_cancelled_invoice))}

Comment: update the question please

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
auction.invoices.get_auction_invoices.item_invoices.\
select("invoices.*, users.*").\
joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = invoices.usable_id").\
order("users.first_name").\
uniq
```